# Error Undefined method `admin?' for nil:NilClass - Seems simple won't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a small problem that ive tried to fix for about an hour. It seems so simple.

If someone goes to the user index view i want them redirected to root url. Unless they're admin.

Any clues how to fix?

Thank you for any help in advance.

I have a simple test

```
  test "should redirect index when not logged in" do
    get :index
    assert_redirected_to login_url
  end
```

But i receive this error.

```
  1) Error:
UsersControllerTest#test_should_redirect_index_when_not_logged_in:
NoMethodError: undefined method `admin?' for nil:NilClass
    app/controllers/users_controller.rb:78:in `admin_user'
    test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:42:in `block in <class:UsersControllerTest>'
```

My admin_user method in User Controller is below

```
# Confirms an admin user.
def admin_user
  redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.admin?
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if your user has been logged in. If he is not, `current_user` will be `nil`. You may want to check this in `admin_user` method too.

```
redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.try(:admin?)
```

Answer (score 1):

`current_user` is nil.

So something like this:

```
redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user && current_user.admin?
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the rails `try` method to add all the objects.

```
redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.try(:admin?)
```

Comment: What is the difference between your answer and the 1st answer on this question, i.e.: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31404125/1047207